# String.format xaml Phone Number

Tags: xaml, data-annotations

How do I format a string property to a phone number format in xaml **without a value converter**. I'm also using 
data annotation [Phone].
I tried this but its not working.

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Phone, StringFormat=\{0:(000)000\-0000\}}"/>
```

Comment: Not working how?  Also, use a damned value converter.  You'd probably be over this problem if you did :)  Create a type to store the phone number and a IVC to convert that type to text and back again.  Would be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: @Will From the language you use i see that you also don't love value converter... Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the input type? String? Give an example of the data you use...

Comment: No, actually, value converters are very useful.  I love them.  You should too.

Comment: @codekaizen     [Phone]
                public string Phone { get; set; }

Comment: That's why it won't work. The '0' formatting placeholder only works on numeric types, and strings are not silently coerced to numeric types in .Net. If you want to use this approach, you need to either expose the value converted to a numeric type (e.g. Int64 or BigInteger likely), or to use a more appropriate mechanism of value conversion, like a value converter or just format it in the view model, which is the solution I'd choose.

Comment: Also note that DataAnnotations are not interpreted by WPF. In ASP.Net, there is a service to generate the appropriate view markup given a model with this attribution. This does not exist in WPF. Over here we use MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do this on a first cut:

```
public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Contact _contact;

    public ContactViewModel(Contact contact)
    {
        _contact = contact;
    }

    public String Phone
    {
        get
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder(_contact.Phone);
            builder.Insert(6, '-');
            builder.Insert(3, ')');
            builder.Insert(0, '(');
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML, I'd just bind to the `Phone` property, but use this view model adapter layer instead of binding directly on the model object. This is a View Model's most prominent feature: to adapt the model to the view.